# vector of bool to gmp integer

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, gmp

I looked a bit at `mpz_import` but I am not yet sure of its usage (I apologize, I am a newbie in programming with gmp). I have a `std::vector<bool>`, which was in the past my rather inefficient way to deal with big numbers. Numbers can get larger than 32 or 64 bit sometimes and I also have smaller numbers, I am hoping that gmp handles this efficiently. Now I want to clean my old code and use gmp instead.

I work in C++. So my question is what is the correct way to convert `vector<bool>` to `mpz_t`. In my application, I really don't care about the value of the integer, as long as two different vectors (compared by their content) represent distinct gmp integers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think `mpz_import` would work properly. So I ended up using the following

```
mpz_t n; mpz_init(n);

for (size_t i = bignum.size(); i --> 0; )
  if (bignum[i]) mpz_setbit(n,i);
```